# Javascript animations don't work on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several animations in my scripts, but they don't work.  I can't identify the problem.  What might prevent these animations from running?

I have tried each animation in its own html page, they work fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $timeline_block = $('.cd-timeline-block');

  //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
  $timeline_block.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75) {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
    }
  });

  //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $timeline_block.each(function(){
      if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
        $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The animations don't work once incorporated into my site.

Comment: The complete repo: https://github.com/ashd32/2019Portfolio

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw your repo. In index.html in line 542 add a class `cssanimations`

```
    <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container cssanimations">
```

By the way you used `body` tag inside `body` tag. Surly that is not right.

Comment: Thank you @Iftifar_Taz!